# Close a running app from my react native app

Tags: react-native

Hello guys I just wanna know how to stop an application that I launched from my react native application using:

```
Linking.openURL()
```

I want to stop that application in a :

```
setTimeout(()=>{
      //// what to write here to close the app above
   },10000)
```

Need help please. I couldn't found a method that does this in Linking module of react-native 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html

Comment: Have you opened another app from openUrl()? and which app you want to close?

Comment: i already opened google maps using openUrl('geo:lat,lng') and i want to close it

Comment: You can't close another app from one app. It's not practically possible.